# Win7 register in registry is failed

Tags: c++, windows-7, registry

I'm trying to register the DLL in Win7 registry (in XP its working). The DllRegisterServer is implemented as follow:

1. Succeeded - Call the RegCreateKeyEx function to register new key : \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NEWKEY
2. Failed - Call the RegCreateKeyEx function to register new key : \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\NEWKEY

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: What's not working? Are you seeing errors? Unexpected behavior? What have you already tried? Are you running your registration routine elevated?

Comment: What is the return value from `RegCreateKeyEx()` ?

Comment: does the user have the access rights to modify the registry?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API includes a function `GetLastError()`. Most functions, including the registry access function include the error reporting by the LastError paradigma.

When you have your own code to register the DLL, i.e. you debug your `DllRegisterServer`, did you call GetLastError after a failed function call? You will get an idea of the reason, when you evaluate the return value of `GetLastError()`.